# Socket.IO : Forcing flash sockets, "No transport available"

Tags: javascript, flash, sockets, websocket, socket.io

**PROBLEM :**

I am having problems getting socket.IO to connect in some circumstances, so wanted to make sure that all of the transport methods were working fine. When I force flashflash sockets I get the error "No transport available". The WebSocketMain.swf file is located in the same directory as the html file.

I am using this code to connect to the socket,

```
var socket = new io.Socket(null,{port: 8086, rememberTransport:false, transports:['flashsocket']});
```

**EXAMPLE :** http://thebeer.co/labs/realTime.php

(explore the source for more info, my JS is under the included socket.io pulgin script)

Comment: Is it works fine with other transports?

Comment: @emmerman if I don't specify a transport it will connect. Chrome testing only.

Comment: Look at `Flashsocket.check` function and run `if` conditions from there step by step to figure where problem is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At least part of the problem is

```
if (window.WebSocket) return;
```

on line 1887 of socket.io.js.

It doesn't configure flash if WebSockets are already working. comment out that line if you need to test it.

Comment: the check now happens in WS.check(): 
`WS.check = function () {
    return ('WebSocket' in global && !('__addTask' in WebSocket))
          || 'MozWebSocket' in global;
  };`